# Change CSS output filename in Compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I am using Compass to compile .scss files to .css files. I have a file called app.scss which I want to compile to foundation.css.

The problem is that I can't simply rename app.scss to foundation.scss because I end up with a circular import error (app.scss includes the following line: `@import "foundation";`).

Is there a way for Compass to rename app.scss to foundation.css during the compiling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to change `app.scss` to `_app.scss`, and then have a `foundation.scss` that does nothing but import the `_app.scss`.